# pm2 + EC2 instance + bootstrap script = hang?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pm2

Strange problem appears when I try to launch AWS EC2 instance with pm2

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
--count ${INSTANCE_COUNT} \
--image-id ${IMAGE_ID} \
--region ${REGION} \
--instance-type ${INSTANCE_TYPE} \
--iam-instance-profile Name=${IAM_ROLE} \
--security-group-ids ${SECURITY_GROUP} \
--key-name ${KEY_NAME} \
--subnet-id ${SUBNET_ID} \
--user-data ${BOOTSTRAP}
```

where ${BOOTSTRAP} is url to my file `BOOTSTRAP='file://ec2-bootstrap.sh'`.

The problem is that it has the following row which hangs while trying to start pm2 daemon:

```
pm2 start ${SERVER_HOME}/index.js --ignore-watch="database node_modules" --watch -- -p80
```

After it happens, processor load is 100% high and virtual memory runs out of its size.

The only things I could find are somehow about slave instances + `stdin`, e.g. look [here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/659#issuecomment-61445692) or [here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/887), but both of these articles are too far away from solving my problem.

When I try to run this command manually it works just fine, very fast and as expected, but if I try to run it with `at`, let's say

```
echo '<<the command here>> > ~/test.log' | at now + 1 min
```

the problem is reproduced. It also hangs...

How to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time working on this problem in a CentOS environment, also on AWS. I was in the same place as you, and ended up being unable to solve it. Opening a ticket with AWS and working with a support rep resulted in the discovery that, as far as I can tell, PM2 requires an interactive terminal session to run some of its commands.

I've opened an issue on the [PM2 Github repository](http://github.com/Unitech/PM2), but until that's resolved, your best bet might be to use something like [forever](http://github.com/foreverjs/forever) instead using the -w and --watchIgnore flags.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358286/2960953) discusses how to set up watching for a process and ignore certain files in forever.

e: It looks like this was fixed by PM2 developers in late 2016 by [refactoring the startup system](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2559).

Comment: I stumbled accross this post while looking for a solution to my problem, it seems pm2 does not like virtual environments: I have rented a VPS running Debian and it completely freezes when pm2 is used to run some node applications. Evil and hard-to-trace error! I won't use it anymore.